# Best Practice with jquery functions and ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm new to ajax and want to best understand how to write my jQuery code so that then a page is called via ajax, my jQuery functions (simple stuff like slideshows and overlays) will still work.

Below is what I'm currently doing to make my jquery work on a stand alone page without ajax.

```
$('.microContentWrap').click(function(){

    //perform some functions

});
```

In order to make this same function work when this page has been loaded via ajax, I'm duplicating my code and binding it to a div called "ajax-wrapper" that loads normally on this page. Without this step, the above code was not executing on the ajax page.

```
$("ajax-wrapper").on("click", ".microContentWrap", function() { 

    //exact same functions as above

});
```

Both of these things work, but is this the most efficient way? Seems repetitive to do this two step process for every single function in my file.

Comment: it's because microContent gets destroyed and re-added I'm guessing, meaning it's a dynamic element which usually means you bind the click event on the static parent to run the fnc

Comment: What two-step process?  You replace the first approach with the second approach.  It's one step either way.

Comment: What do you mean by *"two step process"*? Almost seems like you haven't provided enough information for anyone to help

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs you are right. It's being destroyed. After reading through all these comments, I realized I could just bind everything to the body element and then not have a need repeat the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("ajax-wrapper").on("click", ".microContentWrap", function() { 

    //exact same functions as above

});
```

Is saying: "when I click within 'ajax-wrapper' check to see if the element I clicked is 'microContentWrap', if it is, then do this function". The benefit of this approach is that 'microContentWrap' doesn't need to exist when you bind the click even listener.

Another approach would be to add the event listener to 'microContentWrap' in your ajax callback function. So for example:

```
$.ajax({
    url:"getvalue.php",  
    success:function(data) {
         $('body').append('<div class="microContentWrap"></div>');
         $('.microContentWrap').click(function(){}); 
    }
  });
```

Comment: The second approach is what we in the industry call a Bad Idea. Mainly because every time you do that ajax call, another event handler is added, and the previously attached one is left dangling, potentially leaking memory. Better to use the first option.

Comment: I mean the same could be said about putting event binding in a function "every time you do that function call, another event handler is added..." If he's only planning on _successfully_ calling that ajax a single time -- I don't see the issue. The first approach is "I really don't know when this element will exist or not" where as the second is "I know exactly when this element will exist or not". The second approach is more reminiscent of dependency injection imo.

Comment: I have to agree with @MikeMcCaughan. Every single successful AJAX call you will be binding additional event handlers. This is an anti-pattern in general and has nothing to do with dependency injection (dependency injection typically checks of dependencies have been loaded, and if it is, will not reload). The best way is to simply listen to the event bubbling up to a parent that is guaranteed to exist at runtime (the first method). It doesn't care if the element exists or not. It simply listens to the event, and checks if the event is emitted by `.microContentWrap`. This is way more efficient.

Comment: Again, if you are calling this service more than once, add a check -- but that's not a flaw in the pattern. And yes, this would qualify as dependency injection. `.microContentWrap` depends on the the success of the ajax call, creating/binding the element should be bound to it imo. Binding a click to a large parent element and checking every time if its the right child element is not more efficient than directly binding it to the element you need.

Comment: But you are binding an event listener to **multiple elements multiple times over**, and that is IMHO a major performance issue when you have (1) many `.microContentWrap` appended per call, and (2) many calls being made in the same document—I believe you are missing the point here. When listening to event bubbling, you only listen to the one click event that bubbles up.

Comment: My assumption was that there would be a singular ajax call and a singular `.microContentWrap`element that would be appended, and bound. Because OP was vague with his question I think we're just envisioning different scenarios. What I thought OP meant was "I want to load some content on my page, and I also want to bind a click event to part of the content loaded". If that's the case I think it makes more sense to be specific with the event binding, rather than using the delegate. There's a reason everything isn't bound with `$('body').on('click', '.theElementIActuallyWant', function(){})`

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this was actually very simple, I just didn't understand binding. The problem I was having was that the ajax-wrapper gets destroyed after the microContent comes in. On other non-ajax pages there was no ajax-wrapper which is why I thought there needed to be two functions. By binding to the body, I eliminated the issue.

```
$("ajax-wrapper").on("click", ".microContentWrap", function() { 

    //exact same functions as above

});
```